# Azure Table Storage - 501 Not Implemented

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage, azure-tablequery

I'm following this guide for using Azure Tables: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/overview/azure/data.tables-readme-pre which uses the Azure.Data.Tables NuGet package.

I can successfully save a row and see it in the storage explorer within the Azure portal, however when trying to do a simple query, I'm getting back:

```
Unhandled exception. Azure.RequestFailedException: Service request failed.
Status: 501 (Not Implemented)

Content:
{"odata.error":{"code":"NotImplemented","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"The requested operation is not implemented on the specified resource.\nRequestId:0137da3a-f002-0031-19
d6-5234ab000000\nTime:2021-05-27T08:59:39.8919922Z"}}}
```

My code for the query is:

```
    var entities = _tableClient
        .Query<TableEntity>(t => t.PartitionKey == PartitionKey)
        .ToList();
```

Comment: can you try without .ToList(); ?

Comment: same thing, but error happens when I iterate

Comment: TableQuery<TableEntity> query = new TableQuery<TableEntity>().Where(TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("PartitionKey", QueryComparisons.Equal, partitionKey)); this one?

Comment: What library/package are those types from?

Comment: Maybe the SDK isn't fully functional yet as it's stated to still be in beta. Doing the same with the `Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table` package using `var query = table.CreateQuery<TableEntity>().Where(x => x.PartitionKey == "test").ToList();` seems to work without issue for me. Haven't tried the beta package.

Comment: @404 yes I'm trying that package now, and it works fine.

Comment: Have to say the number of client libraries makes this very confusing

Comment: I am able to run the code above without any issues against a table in my storage account. Can you share your complete code or provide more details?

Comment: In my case, the problem was with connection_string, in the endpoint I've included the table name as well, that's why it wasn't working. After just giving the the url without table it is working fine.

Answer (score 2):

I ran in to this exact problem as well, and although it doesn't seem to be documented anywhere, the following worked for me:

```cs
var token = new DefaultAzureCredential();
var tableServiceClient = new TableServiceClient(new Uri($"https://{storageAccountName}.table.core.windows.net/"), token);
var client = tableServiceClient.GetTableClient(tableName);
var entities = client.Query<MyEntity>(filter: $"PartitionKey eq '{partKey}'");
```

I don't exactly understand why the direct creation of TableClient:

```cs
new TableClient(new Uri($"https://{storageAccountName}.table.core.windows.net/{tableName}"), tableName, token);
```

doesn't work, but going through TableServiceClient first worked for me. Give that a try.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue in the java SDK when i created the client like so:

```
new TableClientBuilder()   
        .endpoint("https://{storageAccountName}.table.core.windows.net/{tableName}")
                .sasToken(sas)
                .tableName(tableName)
                .buildClient()
```

So what i did wrong was putting the table name as part of the endpoint and removing it stopped the exception.

Answer (score 0):

The OP's problem was that they were using `==` instead of `eq` for their equality operator, as `==` is not one of [the supported query comparison operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/querying-tables-and-entities#supported-comparison-operators).

I had a different problem, but with the same error, so I thought I'd share my answer. I started receiving the same error after updating to the latest `Azure.Data.Tables` NuGet package, where I was getting an error like:

> Status: 501 (Not Implemented)
>
> ErrorCode: NotImplemented
>
> Content:
> {"odata.error":{"code":"NotImplemented","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"The requested operation is not implemented on the specified resource.\nRequestId:ce4208b5-b002-0001-63f9-59956d000000\nTime:2024-02-07T19:10:04.3685354Z"}}}

My issue was I using a boolean in my query filter like this:

```
filter += $" and (OperationSuccessful eq {parameters.Successful})";
```

Where `parameters.Successful` is a boolean. This resulted in a query filter like:

> "(PartitionKey eq 'Some partition key') and (OperationSuccessful eq True)"

The NuGet package update seems to have introduced a breaking change where the query is now case-sensitive, so having "True" and "False" be capitalized breaks the OData query.

The solution was to update the code to:

```
filter += $" and (OperationSuccessful eq {parameters.Successful.ToString().ToLower()})";
```

Which results in the query looking like this instead:

> "(PartitionKey eq 'Some partition key') and (OperationSuccessful eq true)"

It's a bit of a hassle, but it got things going again for me.