# How to filter boolean value in Azure Table Storage using OData filters?

Tags: c#, .net-core, odata, azure-table-storage, azure-tablequery

I'm trying to filter Azure Table Storage using OData filters but for boolean values it always returns null results.

Here is list of filters that i've already tried:

- IsBlocked eq {false}
- IsBlocked eq '{false}'
- IsBlocked eq 'false'
- IsBlocked eq false
- IsBlocked eq boolean'{false}'
- IsBlocked eq bool'{false}'

Comment: `IsBlocked eq false` should have worked. Can you please edit your question and include how the data looks like in your table?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in my entire filter I had

`$"(Code eq '{code}') and (IsBlocked eq false)"`

rather than

`$"(Code eq '{code}') and IsBlocked eq false"`

I shouldn't put brackets...

Answer (score 0):

It's weird that removing the parenthesis worked for you, as they work fine for me.

I had [a similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77957415/602585), but the issue was that I was converting a bool variable to a string which resulted in the value being "True" or "False", but the capital letters broke the OData query. It seems it only accepts "true" or "false". Just thought I'd mention this for others that stumble across this with the same problem.